# Why doesn't this key handler work without an alert?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the [Bootstrap button plugin](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/#button-plugin) to render a list of checkboxes as buttons. This works great except for when "clicking" the buttons using the spacebar. The default behavior of the Bootstrap example when pressing space with the focus on one of the checkbox buttons is that the label receives the "active" class but the checkbox element doesn't actually get checked. I added the following javascript to programatically click the label when the spacebar is pressed. If I put an alert in there somewhere, even at the end of the handler, it works as expected. Without an alert the spacebar doesn't toggle the button state OR check the checkbox.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        window.onkeydown = function(event) {
            if(event.keyCode === 32 && $(event.target).hasClass('cabin-cb')) {
                //alert('hi'); 
                event.preventDefault();
                //alert('hi');
                $(event.target).closest('label').click();
                //alert('hi');
            }
        };            
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Trigger the "click" event in something like a timeout handler so that it happens *after* the "keydown" event has run its course:

```
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(event.target).closest('label').click();
  }, 1);
```

You could do it with `Promise.resolve()` or `requestAnimationFrame()` too; the point is to have the "click" happen once the keyboard processing has finished.